# How to add sub totals for dynamic columns in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

how to add sub totals for dynamic columns in gridview

```
region  customer 01-feb-2012 02-feb-2012 ...... 29-feb-2012 Total
chennai xxx               10          20                       30
        yyy               10                                   10
        Total             20          20                       40
mumbai  aaa               20                                   20
        bbb                           10                       10
        Total             20          10                       30
```

No. of Columns vary depends upon the days in the selected month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have given sample code for u...

refer this code in your code,it will calculate total value dynamically.use DataRowBound Properties,its working...

Aspx Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdBoardingListReport" runat="server" CellPadding="2" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Both" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="false">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
<EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
<FooterStyle BackColor="#c5c5c5" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
<HeaderStyle CssClass="clsReportGridHeader" BackColor="#c5c5c5" Font-Size="10"/>
<PagerStyle BackColor="#39afd9" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Sl.No" HeaderText="slno" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="fd_name" HeaderText="Name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="fd_total" HeaderText="Total"/>
</Columns>
<RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Bind :

```
private void bindFreePassReport()
{
if (!(Session["FreePassReceive"] == null))
{
DataTable freePassReceive = (DataTable)Session["FreePassReceive"];

if (freePassReceive.Rows.Count > 1)
{
grdFreePassReport.DataSource = freePassReceive;
grdFreePassReport.DataBind();
lblTitle.Text = Session["FreePassReportTitle"].ToString();
}
else
{
grdFreePassReport.DataSource = null;
grdFreePassReport.DataBind();
}
}
}
```

Datarow Bound:

```
int Total;
protected void grdBordingPlace_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
total += Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[2].Text);
}
else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
{
e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Total" + " : ";
e.Row.Cells[2].Text = total.ToString();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of computing it in the grid view, I will suggest you to do it at data table level and than bind the data table with the grid view, as doing it at grid view will make it complex.